# Tokens and exchanges

Tags: tokens, exchanges

**Token help**

We have created a utility token do we place our total supply on one exchange or divide and distribute portions of our total supply on multiple exchanges?

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood how tokens work (and exchanges).

When you create a smart contract for a token, the contract contains all the tokens. Then you can send the tokens somewhere. If you have a very good team behind the token and good connections to exchanges, you may get your token listed on some exchange and they start trading with it.

So it's not a question of "how much should we place in exchanges". If you get your token listed in any (centralized) exchange it's a huge thing already. 99,99% of tokens do not get listed I'd guess.